# How to upgrade to latest PHP, MySQL, and phpmyadmin on CentOS 5.8 (32bit)?

Tags: mysql, php, centos, centos5

I have searched around on the internet and cannot find a reliable source for installing the latest versions of PHP, MySQL, and phpmyadmin on CentOS 5.8 32bit with apache. I have tried a couple times, with no luck. Each time corrupted my server.

I'm tired of assuming what's correct and screwing up my server / wasting time. I figured I would come here to get a legitimate answer that actually works, straight from the community that knows what they're actually doing.

It would also be cool if it could be done with YUM for automatic future updates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I installed [IUS](http://iuscommunity.org/) and [RPM Forge](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge/) Release and then removed old packages. with a dump from MySQL for sure. and then re-installed PHP54 and MySQL55.

assuming it's CentOS/RHL 5 and you have old PHP & MySQL installed

first find all packges related to php by:

```
rpm -qa | grep php
```

then remove matched packages:

```
yum remove [packages]
```

then search for mysql:

```
rpm -qa | grep mysql
```

again remove matched packages:

```
yum remove [packages]
```

now install IUS & RPMForge release for latest versions of PHP and MySQL:

```
wget http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
wget http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/5/i386/ius-release-1.0-10.ius.el5.noarch.rpm
wget http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm
```

Install DAG's GPG key :

```
rpm --import http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
```

then install those rpms:

```
rpm -i epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
rpm -i ius-release-1.0-10.ius.el5.noarch.rpm
rpm -i rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.*.rpm
```

now check for an update:

```
yum update
```

to install PHP54 & MySQL55:

```
yum install php54 mysql55-server
```

all dependencies will be installed

to install module for PHP applications that use MySQL databases:

```
yum install php54-mysql
```

restart apache:

```
service httpd restart
```

run mysql secure installation:

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

restart mysqld:

```
service mysqld restart
```

I think It's done.

and for exporting MySQL database:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > all_databases.sql
```

to import that database I think this works:

```
mysql -u root -p < all_databases.sql
```

as you installed IUS release you can easily download latest versions of phpMyAdmin:

assuming you have installd phpMyAdmin package.
remove it first:

```
yum remove phpMyAdmin
```

install phpMyAdmin**3**:

```
yum install phpMyAdmin3
```

then look for phpMyAdmin directory where files are stored:

```
whereis phpMyAdmin
```

make a symbolic link of the directory that contains phpMyAdmin management interface where it is accessible from Apache

```
ln -s [phpMyAdmin Directory]
```

if you recive forbidden error while accessing phpMyAdmin from browser try this:

```
chown -h [user]:[group] [Path to phpMyAdmin  symbolic link]
```

Comment: Could you please edit your answer with commands for doing what you did?

Comment: Yes Sure, I edited my answer.

Comment: Of Course, Added that step.

Comment: your welcome, added phpMyAdmin section.

Comment: phpmyadmin3 didnt work because it requires php53 for everything.

Comment: what if you download phpMyAdmin form http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php and edit the config manually?

Comment: How would anyone new to CentOS/Linux EVER figure this out? And I'm not joking here.      Does this guide still hold true today (a year after it was posted)?

Comment: They will definitely figure this out. You can ask whoever accepted this answer and voted up. and what do you exactly want to earn from this comment?

Answer (score 1):

```
# yum install --enablerepo=ius-archive php53u-mysql
# yum install --enablerepo=ius-archive phpMyAdmin3
```

Works now on RHEL 5.5

Comment: Not the latest...